# Why is remark not shown when executed with Root?

Tags: polkadot-js, sudo, root

I was wondering why the Polkadot JS Apps are not displaying a remark when executed via Root (e.g., sudo) origin?

Is there any way to view the remark this way? I am interested for the case of voting on a remark in a referendum.

Comment: Can you please share reproduction steps, and how you are trying to "view" them?

Comment: 1. Run relay node in dev mode (template in Substrate repo) 

2. Execute sudo(remark(...))

3. In Polkadot-JS Apps look at the block in which the sudo extrinsic was successful. It just lists sudo whereas a normal remark is listed under extrinsics. I am wondering if there is any way to view the sudo(remark(...))), maybe with a block explorer like Subscan if it exists? I would like to propose a remark to governance and have it executed and refer to it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you wrap a call, only the root is displayed, this means -

- `utility.batch([ system.remark(...), ... ])` will show the batch transaction under extrinsics
- `sudo.sudo(system.remark(...))` will show the sudo transaction under extrinsics

In all case it will display the extrinsic as retrieved from the block and as submitted to the chain. Wrapping shows the wrapper.

Obviously when you expand the wrapper, be it `batch/sudo/sub`/etc it will show the information contained in the tx - in this case the remark.

Comment: Thanks, seems like there also was an upgrade of the Polkadot Apps which touched the illustration of the block contents. Works perfectly fine now. Seems like I was blind before.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `remark_with_event`. Otherwise, you can not see the event.

Can this answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately, `remark_with_event` cannot be called from root origin as it requires a signature.